# How I can generate unique employee id in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to generate unique employee id like first letter of first name + first letter of last name + 1 in SQL using select statement.

For example:

- If employee name is Rahul Khandekar, then Employee Id will be RK1.
- If new employee joins with name Rakesh Kumar, then Employee Id will be RK2.
- If new employee joins with name Krishna Pawar, then Employee Id will be KP1.

Comment: Ah... "Smart IDs" strike again... They were all the rage back in the '80s.

Comment: How is this better than just an autonumber / identity identifier?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using T-SQL syntax - but you could do something like this.  I'm assuming it's always 2 characters and then your number (however long)

```
SELECT 'RK' + CONVERT(varchar(10),ISNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING(EmployeeID,3,10)),0)+1)
  FROM Employees
 WHERE EmployeeID LIKE 'RK%'
```